# RL solutions for OpenAI Gym environments?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, deep-rl, open-ai, ddpg, gym

Is there any place where people share their agent's settings for solving OpenAI Gym Environments?

For example, I'd like to know what are good parameters for a DDPG agent to learn the task in Reacher-v2. I believe that a lot of people tried to solve it and maybe they shared their solution for achieving better performance.

Answer (score 1):

Specific hyperparameters for *Reacher-v2*, from Table 10 in [Universal Successor Features for Transfer Reinforcement Learning](https://arxiv.org/abs/2001.04025):

| Hyperparameter | DDPG | DDPG + USFs | HER | HER + USFs |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Actor Learning Rate | 1e-4 | 1e-4 | 1e-3 | 1e-4 |
| Critic Learning Rate | 1e-3 | 1e-3 | 1e-4 | 1e-3 |
| Loss Weight λ | N/A | 1e-4 | N/A | 0.01 |
| Batch Size | 64 | 64 | 64 | 64 |
| Discount Factor γ | 0.99 | 0.99 | 0.99 | 0.99 |
| HER Future Steps | N/A | N/A | 50 | 50 |
| HER Buffer Sampling Probability | N/A | N/A | 0.5 | 0.5 |

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of spread throughout the internet. There are tons of [gists](https://gist.github.com/gkhayes/3d154e0505e31d6367be22ed3da2e955) and [repos](https://github.com/sourcecode369/deep-reinforcement-learning), there are contests and topics on kaggle. I do not think there is one centralized repository of this sort of thing other than individuals who have curated some list(which is the repo I linked), although perhaps you could make one!